# Computed property in handlebar #if not updating

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use the following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
    {{#if logged_in}}
        Logged in
    {{else}}
        Not logged in
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

with the model:

```
App.Login = DS.Model.extend({
    access_token: DS.attr('string'),
    logged_in: function() {
        return (this.get('access_token') != null);
    }.property('access_token')
});
```

to display the user's logged-in state.

The access_token is being set via an async callback in the Route's setupController:

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);

        // call async login method
        window.setInterval(function test() {
            model.set('access_token', 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN');
            console.log(model.get('access_token'));
        }, 5000);
    },
    model: function() {
        return App.Login.find();
    }
});
```

The problem is logged_in never seems to change (even though the model.set line is executed and 'access_token' is updated). Am I doing something wrong or should I be filing a bug?

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8eHq/

Comment: The problem is not the if helper. If you log model.get("logged_in"), you will see that it returns undefined. What version are you using in your fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the model to `App.Login.find()` which returns an enumerable, not a single object. One way to do it, is to set the model to a single object:

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Login.find(1);
    }
});
```

Or if you are going to use a dynamic route (e.g. users/login/9):

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Login.find(params.id);
    }
});
```